# Collapsing DIV in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, clearfix

If you view the following website in IE9 (or any other modern browser) you will see the effect I am going for.
However viewed in IE8 or lower the header DIV that contains the mans photo collapses to what appears to be 0 height.
I have tried min-height and also the clearfix, but nada.

http://www.adrianwaddingham.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just setting the height and making it `!important`, such as:

```
min-height: (yourheight)px!important;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: it was an answer, it was asking him to try that. I just worded it differently.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it still collapses - I am looking via Adobe browsers labs - not sure if someone could check using standard IE8? thanks

Comment: IE tester is helpful for testing in older versions of IE. It can be downloaded here http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage